# QuickOSM returns wrong results

Tags: qgis, quickosm

I use to download layers on QGIS by Overpass using the excellent plug-in "QuickOSM".
I'm wondering why there is some wrong results, especially with points layers.
For example,  if we download the points with the key "amenity" and the value "parking" near from the Marseille's train station (France), we get some "barrier_lift_gate" which has no value for the key "amenity", and one which have the value "bicycle_parking".[image]

Does anyone understand why ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may be coming in as it's listed as a part of the parking amenity (see screenshot below).

Try unchecking 'Relation' in your query and see if that works better.

[image]

Comment: The points are still there uncheking "Relation". But they seem to disapear uncheking "way". Maybe because a barrier_lift_gate is tagged as part of a way entering / exiting a parking ?

Comment: Unchecking "relation" won't change anything indeed. These "lift_gates" are part of the geometry of the "amenity_parking" in OSM, that's why fetching the "amenity=parking" ALSO fetches the nodes belongings to the line. Maybe you can tweak the Overpass query to not add the tags of "child" objects. (only the coordinates are enough in your case) but I never tried. Or you need to create a Processing model to clean your dataset.