# Automatic "Extract by Expression" processing with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

Refering to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345200/quickosm-returns-wrong-results) and particulary the etrimaille's comment, I want to clean my dataset created from OSM data in QGIS.
In each layer, I want to extract the entities having a specific key and value, using the "extractbyexpression" processing.

It works well using directly the former key and value :

```
new_layer = processing.run("qgis:extractbyexpression", {'INPUT': layer, 'EXPRESSION':'"amenity" ILIKE \'parking\'', 'OUTPUT':'memory:'})['OUTPUT']
```

But if I use variables in the expression, all the features are selected, without filtering (it selects the children objects too) :

```
key = "amenity"
value = "parking"
expression = "'"+"\\"+'"'+str(key)+"\\"+'"'+" ILIKE "+"\\"+"'"+str(value)+"\\"+"'"+"'"
new_layer = processing.run("qgis:extractbyexpression", {'INPUT': layer, 'EXPRESSION':expression, 'OUTPUT':'memory:'})['OUTPUT']
```

I need to proceed this way because I have a lot of layers, and I don't want to write the code for each layer.
I suppose my expression is not correctly written, because the result of the second process should be the same as the first.

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Try using [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of +.

Comment: `exp = """"{0}" ILIKE '{1}'""".format(key,value)`

Comment: Indeed, it works. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why QGIS is inserting multiple backslashes (please comment if you know why) but in your case it does not seem to be needed.

Try using [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and skip the backslashes:

```
exp = """"{0}" ILIKE '{1}'""".format(key,value)
```

I had to enclose everything in three double quotes to get the "internal" single and double quotes to work.

Comment: Not sure i understood well your doubt, but if it can help : a backslash in a string considers the next caracter as a str and not as a format element to interpret. If you want to put a "\" in a string as text, you have to write `string = "\\"`, otherwhise python considers the second quotation mark as text, and is waiting for you to close the quotation

Comment: However, thank you very much for the "format" solution you suggested, that works, and that looks better